# open .phtml files displays code in browser

Tags: php, html, netbeans

I have saved my view file in netbeans IDE as .phtml. File has both php scripting and HTML5 within it.

Through WAMP, when i try to open, only the coding is displayed..

Could anyone help please??

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try creating a .htaccess file with the following content

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .phtml
AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .phtml
```

If it works, you know your Server is not configured to run phtml as php by default.

Might also try `php5-script` instead of `x-httpd-php5`

Comment: I am sorry am new to php.. am not using any framework.. where to create this .htaccess file???? i tried to create in the same folder where my source file resides. but nope.. its not working.. I am not using any framework... Its just a simple HTML page with one line php script to echo 'Hi'..

Comment: If you look at your httpd.conf, do you seen any AddType entries for php? Have you tried a php extension? Does it work? Maybe you're not allowed to define AddType in .htaccess, because you didn't enable it in httpd.conf.

Answer (score 0):

At times we get posting on the forum where user complain that when they are running a PHP file, the output is the file itself. This means that the script was not recognized as a PHP script and rather it was treated as plain text by the browser. There are two reasons why you can run into this situation to my knowledge.

If you are using short tags for writing PHP script like `<? echo 'Hello World' ?>`, you should ensure that you have short_open_tag INI directive set to '1' in your PHP INI file. If this is not the case the script will not be treated as PHP script. I would prefer PHP script like `<?php echo 'Hello World' ?>`. This is more clear and avoids confusion.

Another reason for running into this situation can be if the PHP file is not saved as ASCII/ANSI. Saving the PHP script in UNICODE/Multi-byte format will again fail the script to be recognized as PHP script. Always save the PHP script as plain text file to avoid running into this situation

**EDIT AFTER THE COMMENT**

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

Or for .htm

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm
```

Comment: am sorry am new to php.. am not using any framework.. where to create this .htaccess file???? i tried to create in the same folder where my source file resides. but nope.. its not working.. I am not using any framework... Its just a simple HTML page with one line php script to echo 'Hi'..

Comment: THANKS A LOT.... i got it.. I included the lines in httpd.conf file and got it.. thank you very much... I included all lines given by you and also Ahatius.. Thanks a lot.. :)